# CiviMail tracking opens stopped working after upgrade to 4.7.x

Tags: civimail, 4.7

CiviMail reports track unique opens and total opens, but after upgrading to 4.7 line, suddenly all mailing register 0 opens. I have testing and opened a test email and CiviMail does not register the open.

Has anyone else noticed this or have an idea why this could be happening?

We are on HostGator shared hosting and have the latest version of Drupal and CiviCRM.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: It worked great before, I don't think anything else was changed.

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced this on a few sites and it turns out the file/directory permissions seem to have changed. I'm not sure if this is in relation to the way 4.7 is packaged, or something on the particular hosts that these sites are on, or what, but I have found that I need to recursively reset permissions after updating, or the tracking doesn't work, click through links don't work, you can't upload images from CiviMail, etc.

From just outside the `civicrm` directory, I do this and it seems to solve it:

```
find civicrm -type d -exec chmod 755 {} ";"

find civicrm -type f -exec chmod 644 {} ";"
```

The first one changes permissions on directories and the second on files.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the source of the email you receive, if should have a:

```
<img src="https://yoursite.org/sites/all/modules/civicrm/extern/open.php?q=91954565" width='1' height='1' alt='' border='0'>
```

at the bottom.
copy the url and paste it, you hopefully have an error message or 404/50x error that should point you into the right direction

If you are using nginx/fastcgi, it's probably that you miss a directive to handle that url

If you don't have that img tag at the bottom of your mail, check if you have the track open checkbox properly set.

Finally: test on gmail, since a wee while, they do display external images. Most of the other mail clients don't display external images by default, so they don't tell your civi that the mail is read.
X+

Comment: I'm experiencing this too - I'm on Wordpress.. Until a few weeks ago it was fine but something has changed and I can't work out what it could be - I've not updated anything on Civi.   I have the above image link and when I copy and paste it I don't get any error messages..