# Tracking on Civimail suddenly stopped working

Tags: wordpress, civimail, tracked-links, mosaico

Morning all

Civi 4.7.14 Wordpress 4.7.5  Using Mosaico (the original one)

All's been going fine for months and months.. suddenly the tracking has stopped working. The emails are being received..just not being reported.

I tried this suggestion: [CiviMail tracking opens stopped working after upgrade to 4.7.x](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/10721/civimail-tracking-opens-stopped-working-after-upgrade-to-4-7-x)

ie cut and paste this link
img src="https://yoursite.org/sites/all/modules/civicrm/extern/open.php?q=91954565" width='1' height='1' alt='' border='0'

but got a black screen- no error message- which I guess is what I'm supposed to get?

thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a tracking image (it's 1x1 px and probably transparent), so you probably don't see it or get an error message.

Once after an upgrade, I somehow ended up with a space before the opening php tag in https://yoursite.org/sites/all/modules/civicrm/extern/url.php which broke tracking (can't have output before the header('Location: ' . $url);)

Answer (score 1):

and the answer is...

dont use tokens to set your paths...

"A workaround is to change the root civicrm token to an absolute path (Credit due to Eli Lisseck for research and workaround solution)"

thanks greatly to [Civimail open tracking is not working for some mailings - inserts var/www/html into path for some mailings but not others](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/16183/civimail-open-tracking-is-not-working-for-some-mailings-inserts-var-www-html-i)